# Connect a message box to a button

Tags: python, button, user-interface, tkinter, messagebox

I want to be able to click the button and have the message box display the code generated. Here's part of the code:

```
global s
letters = [random.choice('BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXYYZ')  for x in range(19)]
numbers = [random.choice('2346789') for x in range(6)]
s = letters + numbers
random.shuffle(s)
s = ''.join(s)

global Code
Code = Entry(state='readonly')

def callback():
    Code = Entry(state='readonly', textvariable=s)

Code.grid(row=0, pady=20)
generate=PhotoImage(file='generate.gif')
G = Button(image=generate , command=callback, compound=CENTER)
G.grid(row=1, padx=206.5, pady=20)
```

Comment: This is Tkinter, right?  It's worth mentioning/tagging the GUI framework you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a few things up with comments:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()

letters = [random.choice('BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXYYZ')  for x in range(19)]
numbers = [random.choice('2346789') for x in range(6)]
s = letters + numbers
random.shuffle(s)
s = ''.join(s)

# Rather than use global variables, which is generally a bad idea, we can make a callback creator function, which takes the formerly global variables as arguments, and simply uses them to create the callback function.
def makeCallback(sVariable):
    def callback():
# This will set the text of the entry
        sVar.set(s)
    return callback

# Use a StringVar to alter the text in the Entry
sVar = StringVar(root)
# You can use an Entry for this, but it seems like a Label is more what you're looking for.
Code = Entry(root, state='readonly', textvariable=sVar)

# Create a callback function
callback = makeCallback(sVar)

Code.grid(row=0, pady=20)
generate=PhotoImage(file='generate.gif')
G = Button(root, image=None , command=callback, compound=CENTER)
G.grid(row=1, padx=206.5, pady=20)
```

Comment: Defining a function within a function is never good form. Look into `lambda` functions instead.

Comment: @The-IT I disagree.  Lambda functions are convenient if you are trying to generate a short function, but defining a function in a function is perfectly acceptable, and even preferable if the generated function is longer than a line or two.

Comment: Your function in a function does not even make sense to me. It takes the parameter `sVariable` and then never uses it. You're much better off deleting that entire part of the code and the `callback = makeCallback(sVar)` and then in button do `command=lambda s=s: sVar.set(s)`.

Comment: Actually, you're right about a couple things - I made a mistake - I meant to write sVariable.set(s), and actually the callback factory isn't necessary here because sVar is defined on the module level - I'm used to writing GUIs inside a class, where you would need a callback factory (or a lambda statement).  But there are plenty of circumstances where callback factories are useful; for instance, what would you do if the callback needs to execute several commands?  The lambda function starts getting pretty unreadable.

Comment: What I would do is that I would have a normal function that calls a bunch of other functions if needed. This can very easily be done from a class. Also, I was always taught that defining a function in a function is always bad form, and I agree because I don't see a situation where that would be necessary.